# Ajax request for .php script being cancelled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to run a script via an ajax call in jquery; however, I am getting no result and seeing a "(canceled)" status in chrome's network view. This only happens when I request the `.php` script, but works fine if I request just a `.txt` file for example; I get an alert of `one\ntwo\nthree` when I change the url to "test.txt" in by `test.html` file below. My webserver is configured correctly and permissions of files are all appropriate. If I request my `.php` script from my browser, it returns "hello" as expected. Below are my three files, why do I get a cancelled request for `test.php` but not for `test.txt`?

### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <title>test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id="b">click</button>
      <script>
         $("#b").bind("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
               url: "test.php", // test.txt works fine
               type: "GET",
               cache: false,
               success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
               }
            });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

### test.txt

```
one
two
three
```

### test.php

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

As mentioned, I get the correct "hello" output if I request `test.php` with my browser so it is executing fine.

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me  22 Oct  1 02:49 test.php`

Comment: Wrap all your stuff in onReady() event, like `$(function(){   $("#b").bind("click", function()... })`

Comment: I don't think this would explain why the `.txt` would work, but try `$("#b").bind("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });`

Comment: It works here, right away copied and pasted. Are you absolutely sure you are not having some `.htaccess` stuff manipulating with the PHP paths/urls??

Comment: There is no logical reason to wait for DOM-ready before firing AJAX requests. And necessarily wrapping your entire code in a DOM-ready block is an anti-pattern as much of it (the non-DOM stuff) could well run effectively before that point in the page's chronology.

Comment: Can you execute test.php?

Comment: Your code should work just fine as-is.

Comment: @davidkonrad It's strange though as my browser requests `test.php` just fine. I noticed the actual url beging request is `test.php?_=1380562557516` but even adding the param my browser gets "hello" fine, but not the ajax request...

Comment: I can say I am using chrome too (regarding the answer below). You must have something that blocks or manipulate the PHP call, but allow loading TXT - thats why I think of .htaccess

Comment: `?_=1380562557516` is because `cache: false` it appends a random number so that the request is different every time.

Comment: Are you using WAMP/LAMP? Is your test.html file outside of your `www` directory? Possibly on your desktop or something by accident?

Comment: I can't explain it, I loaded the page in FF and it was displaying the same behavior, but then when I went back to chrome it was alerting "hello" all of a sudden. kind of embarassing, I'm not the admin for the webserver and no .htaccess file so I don't know what changed :S What to do with this question now?

Comment: Chrome has really aggressive caching. Sometimes it takes a lot of refreshing to reload the cache. Refresh with `CTRL + R` or keep the dev tools open during development (f12). To disable cache while DevTools is open, click f12 (Assuming windows), click the sprocket in the bottom right corner and under the General section (should be open by default) the first checkbox will say "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)..... not really certain that chrome's caching was the issue though. But it sounds like a likely suspect. I've seen this happen pretty badly while doing ajax requests to flat files.

Comment: You should probably delete the question, I suppose. I don't think there's a way to close the question it as resolved/unrelated problem...

Answer (score 2):

`(Canceled)` is frustrating. If you go to `chrome://net-internals/#events` you can see in more detail why your request is getting `(canceled)`. There could be a few reasons why your request is being blocked by Chrome, but you'll get more information about your request at that url. If you're still stuck, edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using WAMP or LAMP.

If your `test.html` file is outside of the web server's `www` directory, the web server will prevent access to your test.php file because it violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This would explain why visiting the test.php file in the browser works fine, and also why this test.html's requests to test.php file are failing.

It may not be this simple, but this is something that gets me every once in a while as well. Especially when I have an index.html laying around on the desktop.